# How to invalidate all tokens for an user in laravel passport?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

In our app when user logs out we invalidate the access token for that particular device this way.

```
$user = $request->user();

$value = $request->bearerToken();
$id = (new Parser())->parse($value)->getHeader('jti');
$token = $user->tokens->find($id);
$token->revoke();
```

But when an user deactivates his/her account, we would like to invalidate all the access tokens from all the devices the user is logged in.
I looked through the document but did not find anything useful. Thanks

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Take a look at the [`HasApiTokens`](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/2.0/src/HasApiTokens.php) trait provided by passport.  The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#installation) recommends adding this trait to your User model.  One of the methods it provides is `tokens()`, which defines a `hasMany` relationship between `Laravel\Passport\Token` and models using the trait.  You can use this to retrieve a list of all of the tokens for a given user:

```
$userTokens = $userInstance->tokens;
```

The token model itself has a `revoke` method:

```
foreach($userTokens as $token) {
    $token->revoke();   
}
```

Comment: We Manually set the revoke field to 1 in the oauth_access_tokens table for a user id. But this seems better

Comment: I manually revoke all previous token of a user but "oauth_refresh_tokens" table still have the entry with revoked "0" value. However "oauth_access_tokens" table is updated with value "1" for revoked. Can you help me this situation or should I not need to worry about this?

Comment: Thanks it work like charm for me. you are super duper guy.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for ME:

```
use Laravel\Passport\Token;

 Token::where('user_id', $user->id)
                ->update(['revoked' => true]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer didn't work for me, the method `revoke()` does not exist.

```
if ($userInstance->tokens->count()) {
        foreach($userInstance->tokens as $token) {
            $token->delete();
        }
    }
```

The code above is working fine for me